# How do I make PHP *actually* release allocated RAM?

Tags: php, windows, memory-management, command-line-interface, ram

I've been testing memory-related stuff lately. Peruse this:

```
$data = load_in_huge_file('test.csv');

while (1)
{
    var_dump(memory_get_usage(false));
    var_dump(memory_get_usage(true));
    sleep(4);
    unset($data);
}
```

For the first loop, this outputs a huge value for the first call to memory_get_usage and the second.

For the second (and further) loop, this outputs a small value for the first call to memory_get_usage and a huge value for the second.

This means that the actual "allocated" memory remains the same, even if I unset the variable holding all the data.

The same thing happens if I do:

```
$data = load_in_huge_file('test.csv');

while (1)
{
    var_dump(memory_get_usage(false));
    var_dump(memory_get_usage(true));
    sleep(4);
    unset($data);
    gc_collect_cycles();
}
```

The "real" memory allocated remains the same after it has been allocated, and is not "freed up".

(The load_in_huge_file function basically runs fopen blabla followed by fclose.)

What do I do about this? It seems that PHP still "uses" the RAM, and my heavy-duty PHP CLI scripts are eventually exhausting all my RAM while processing many CSV files, one by one, and the memory is not being returned.

I don't think I understand what `gc_collect_cycles()` does at all. The manual is unclear to say the least.

Maybe unset() is enough, but it "takes some time"? Maybe the "real" allocated memory is just confusing terminology and doesn't actually mean that the RAM is "occupied"?

(Everything about computers confuse me, perpetually. Nothing can ever be truly learned, without there being endless additional layers of complexity to every last detail.)

Comment: PHP doesn't allocate RAM. It allocates memory, and it's the OS' job to determine which portions of that memory occupy RAM and which ones don't. That said, PHP has a non-deterministic garbage collector that runs as memory pressure rises. Unless you have a real issue you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score -2):

In our programming experience, we dont recommend saving whole data into a variable (to a memory)

It's better to use loop with the help of:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Only load 1 row to a memory, not entire file.

Comment: While I'm aware of the existence of fgetcsv(), I have comments made to myself about how this was a broken nightmare, and that I should "never, ever try to use it again". I'm sure I wrote that for a good reason, and I vaguely remember how problematic it was... But even besides that, my general question still stands.

Comment: PHP is not a desktop application that loads large data memory for whatever reason. 
Processing data using fgetcsv is an efficient way, and many developers are using that.  It is created for that reason to minimize the abuse of memory usage.

Comment: From where did you get the quite absurd idea that only "desktop applications" load large amount of data? It's quite the opposite, I'd say.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that I did use `fgetcsv` after all. So the issue happens even with that method. But again, it's just an example anyway. The basic issue is unrelated to fgetcsv() or CSV files.